# 20.04 software updater hangs with no message

Tags: 20.04, updates

I am using 20.04 64 bit since having upgraded from 18.04 in September 20. The Software Updater worked without issues until it  updated itself sometime in Autumn.

Since then, the notification tells me that there are updates, and opens Software Updater. If I choose to install the listed updates, I only get an empty window which does nothing and only can be closed.

I am now using apt to update, but I would be more comfortable to run Software Updater.

I have re-installed update-manager via apt reinstall, but no avail, behaviour is same. What may be wrong?

Comment: Does `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` show any errors?

Comment: no problems with apt update and upgrade. I am using that way.

Comment: no any hint what I can try?

Comment: I don't know. My Updater is working everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Via apt upgrade, update-manager was updated yesterday to version 1:20.04.10.3.

Now it is running well.

Strange that nobody else seem to have had this problem.